# a property of normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I got a problem in a problem set states as following:

let $G$ be any group, then the subgroup $H$ of $G$ is normal iff, for any $a, b \in G$, $ab \in H$ iff $ba \in H$.

To prove it, the $\to$ part is easy, Just pick the right $x$ in $xax^{-1}$ in normal subgroup's definition.

But I am kind of stuck at $\leftarrow$ case, which basically says:

$\forall a, b \in G, ab \in H \Leftrightarrow ba \in H \to H\ is\ normal.$

I don't really get how this can be derived. Anyone gives me a hand will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a\in H$ and $x\in G$ since $x^{-1}(xa)\in H$, we deduce that $xax^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: thx. that was fast.